# Extract html from website

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a website of close to 800 pages. I want to extract all the HTML and have the code placed in XML. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you want to extract it? From static files? And what kind of XML?

Comment: if they're x-html pages, then `ren *.html *.xml` would do the trick. But really, without knowing how you store your pages, this question can't be answered. Do you have a CMS and store them in a database? A file-based storage mechanism, like individual .html files or one master PHP file that simply includes pages as needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 3):

[PHP Simple HTML-DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for parsing the HTML and good old DOM or [Simple-XML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php) for the XML creating.

Comment: @mario The pages are static HTML pages. I want to extract the HTML only and save it to a XML file. There is no database to use. How do PHP Simple HTML-DOM?

Comment: I think I don't quite get your question. You don't need a DB for Simple HTML-DOM. You just include the library and you're good to go. It does just want you want.